# javascript not working in ie 10 (win7 - 64)

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, javascript

I have tried so many time to enable active scripting, but I cannot seem to get ie 10 (or 11 - i backed down to 10 as a wild stab at solution) to do anything with javascript. Firefox and Chrome both work fine on this machine. In Firefox, I can enter debug-console mode and type "console.log(5+6)" and get 11 echoed. In ie, that just gets the command itself echoed (is there a simpler test of basic operation?). Unfortunately, I can only register Visual Studio via ie so I do need to fix this (otherwise I have done fine just ignoring ie entirely)
(edit 5/12/2015)
I did a further roll back to ie 9, and voila - scripting works AND I was able to register Visual Studio. It should be another year before VS again insists on launching ie so I have some time to retry upgrade (If I don't do it myself, ms update will sneak it in at somepoint).

Thanks all.

Comment: Did you try resetting IE? How about uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Answer (score 0):

By re-installing IE, the problem should get fixed.